# Oracle 12c CentOS PDB Connection from client

Tags: linux, oracle, database-administration, pdb

I have an installation of Oracle 12c on a Windows Server 2012 machine. it has a single PDB (PDBORCL). I have created a user in this PDB and can connect to it from a client machine via SQL Developer using the user/pass for the user i created. the machine hostname and a Service Name of PDBORCL - GREAT!

I tried to replicate the same thing on an Oracle 12c install but I am having an issue of:  TNS listener does not know of a service requested in the connect descriptor.

I have been around online and found maybe i should be putting a reference to the pdb into the tnsnames.ora file on the Cent machine - BUT if i look at the contents of the tnsnames.ora file and listener.ora file on the Windows machine they are still as defaults and contain no reference whatsoever to the PDB "PDBORCL" that i have on the windows installation - so how does it manage to connect fine and my linux box doesnt know what to do?

I guess im looking for general guidance around what should be in the tnsnames.ora file and listener.ora file on my linux machine so that i can access it from a client by referencing the PDB as the Service Name when i connect via SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working on the Linux box. Reason was i was using PDBORCL as the Service Name. after logging on as SYSDBA and querying V$Services i could see that I should have been using pdborcl.localdomain

I'm still not too sure on why the tnsnames on the windows machine didn't explicitly need me to define the pdb though.